# Predefined code styles or css library

Tags: css, website-design

Is there a (free of charge) predefined CSS library for C# code formatting available?  I want to display my C# `<code>` blocks in a web page similar to the way it is displayed in visual studio or even Stackoverflow.

```
<code class="lang-csharp">
//pretty formatted code
</code>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ on my website.  It is a JavaScript library that adds syntax highlighting to code blocks on your page.  It supports C# as well as most other programming languages.